# Trouble getting Data to render on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, render, react-context

I'm working on this application for school in React. I won't go into detail about what the app does.

I'm trying to render data from a third-party API to the page.

[image]

[image]

I can access the properties of each index, but for some reason mapping over each one and printing a property isn't working right.

It's supposed to print here.

Any ideas, anyone?

[image]

Comment: `renderList` is a function so, `<div>{renderList}</div>` should be `<div>{renderList()}</div>`

Comment: Ahhh ok. That didn't work, but it brought to my attention that it shouldn't be a function. I should have just been setting the 'renderList' to 'movies.map...' it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function`renderList` is not returning the array produced by the `map`. You should also return the value from the loop in `renderList` or transform `renderList` into the result of the map instead of a function